# How to indent Javascript source file (CKeditor.js)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to edit [CKeditor source file](http://ckeditor.com/download), which is called ckeditor.js. It is a Javascript file but it is completely unindented and without line breaks. How can indent the code to make it readable by human? I tried "gg=G" under vim with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for "unminifier" or "beautifier" similar to [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: [Unminified, full version of CKEditor is on the Github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev).

Answer (score 3):

The source is not only missing line breaks, but also the variables names are minified.

If you want to edit the CKEditor sources you should [checkout the sources from Github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) and do your changes in a local branch. This way you are able to bring your modified CKEditor always up-to-date.

Comment: I've looked to the git you wrote but the "ckeditor.js" file there is way shorter than the original. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes the final and minified `ckeditor.js` is a composite of many files. these files are listed under `core/`. when you do your changes and you want to have a _release_ build having everything merged into one `ckeditor.js` file you need to use `./dev/builder/build.sh`

Comment: The question was "How can (I) indent the code to make it readable by human", **NOT** "is variables minified", of course they are. What would you answer next? To a C++ question? "Yeah, but the code is in ASCII"

Comment: @davidkonrad The question was "I would like to edit [...] How can indent the code to make it readable by human?". Beautified code is - cause of the _minified_ variables - not necessarily so readable that it can be well edited. So i don't see what should be wrong about pointing that out. But anyway it is a free world and if i have the feeling some day that it could be helpful to say "Yeah, but to code is in ASCII" i will definitely do so ;)